# Is it possible to read cookies of a visitor?

Tags: javascript, cookies

AdSense use javascript to catch the keywords of current page to display relevant ads. But I was recently noticed that it will show ads related to my browsing history too. It seems that the javascript code can read my cookie (in general I mean, e.g. list of domains visited) to display relevant ads.

Is it practically possible to read cookies of a visitor?

Comment: No, but Google's got analytics or adsense running on a significant portion of the web, so they know where you've been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to do so directly due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). (If it were possible, then you could make a page that stole the session of anyone on any domain!)

However, many websites include code from ad providers (read Google) on their page -- so that Google knows that you have visited website X because website X allows Google code to run when someone visits it. When you later visit website Y and it asks Google to display some ads on its behalf, what happens is no mystery.

Google knows all.